# Java memory Mapped File from Windows system

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying something new,
There is an application who send data to a memory-mapped file located at Local\MemFileName

I would like to read it in java,

I tried some tutorials like https://www.baeldung.com/java-mapped-byte-buffer, https://howtodoinjava.com/java7/nio/memory-mapped-files-mappedbytebuffer/

But all seem to read a file in JVM, or I did not understand...

How can I read the content of the file Located in windows system Local\MemFileName

Thanks!

Following: Example code of what i tried

```
public class Main {

private static final String IRSDKMEM_MAP_FILE_NAME = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("Local\\IRSDKMemMapFileName");
private static final String IRSDKDATA_VALID_EVENT  = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("Local\\IRSDKDataValidEvent");

public static final CharSequence charSequence = "Local\\IRSDKMemMapFileName";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    System.out.println(charSequence);

    try (RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(new File(IRSDKMEM_MAP_FILE_NAME), "r")) {
        //Get file channel in read-only mode
        FileChannel fileChannel = file.getChannel();

        //Get direct byte buffer access using channel.map() operation
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fileChannel.size());

        // the buffer now reads the file as if it were loaded in memory.
        System.out.println("Loaded " + buffer.isLoaded());  //prints false
        System.out.println("capacity" + buffer.capacity());  //Get the size based on content size of file

        //You can read the file from this buffer the way you like.
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
            System.out.println((char) buffer.get()); //Print the content of file
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to use a WindowsService.class implementing methods from JNA library, as you can see:
[My Library](https://github.com/JBonifay/irsdk_java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/joffrey/iracing/irsdkjava/windows)

With this I could open a file mapped in Windows system.

All the previous answers was correct for a file accessible from JVM, but from outside the JVM it was impossible.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To read a memory mapped file:

Open a `FileChannel` on the file using `FileChannel.open`.

Invoke the `map` method on the `FileChannel` to create a `MappedByteBuffer` covering the area of the file you want to read.

Read the data from the `MappedByteBuffer`.

Comment: I did it, and I got a NullPointerException.
I saw that if i write instead of read, it create the file Local\\MemFileName in the project directory

Comment: @JoffreyBonifay Please post the code to show what you tried.

Comment: The code you just posted works fine for me! Where do you get a NullPointerException?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: LocalIRSDKMemMapFileName (File not found)
 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
 at io.mappedbus.Main.main(Main.java:21)

Comment: the file "Local\\IRSDKMemMapFileName" is mapped in memory by an application