# Read C#'s MemoryMappedFile in Java

Tags: java, c#, java-io

Hi and happy new year!

I've been looking for a way of doing this piece of code in Java/Kotlin, if possible...

```cs
MemoryMappedFile memfile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MAHMSharedMemory");
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(memfile.CreateViewStream());
br.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

The docs of `OpenExisting` states that:

> Opens an existing memory-mapped file that has the specified name in system memory.

And the docs of `CreateViewStream` tells me:

> Creates a stream that maps to a view of the memory-mapped file.

What would be the Java/Kotlin equivalent of those two methods?

Comment: Java does not have a native way to open named shared memory like that.  Java memory mapped files (through the `FileChannel` class) need to be, well, backed by a file on disk. If you really need to use named shared memory, you could use JNI to do that, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15415998/71141), but really, since you're about to use a Windows specific feature, why use Java at all?

Comment: I see! Went for Java because it’s the language I’m most comfortable with and I want to do a simple jetpack compose desktop app with Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned by [@Etienne de Martel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71141/etienne-de-martel), we're not able to read it straight from Java without any help of JNA or JNI... Luckily there's another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211495/java-memory-mapped-file-from-windows-system) here on SO that pointed my in the right direction...

What I needed to do was:

```java
public interface Kernel32Impl extends com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32 {
    Kernel32Impl KERNEL_32 = Native.load("kernel32", Kernel32Impl.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    HANDLE OpenFileMapping(int lfProtect, boolean bInherit, String lpName);
    HANDLE OpenEvent(int i, boolean bManualReset, String lpName);
}
```

and finally in Kotlin

```kotlin
class WindowsService {

    var lastError: Int = 0
        private set

    fun openMemoryMapFile(filename: String): WinNT.HANDLE? {
        val memMapFile = Kernel32Impl.KERNEL_32.OpenFileMapping(WinNT.SECTION_MAP_READ, false, filename)
        lastError = Kernel32Impl.KERNEL_32.GetLastError()

        return memMapFile
    }

    fun closeHandle(handle: WinNT.HANDLE) {
        Kernel32Impl.KERNEL_32.CloseHandle(handle)
    }

    fun mapViewOfFile(handle: WinNT.HANDLE?): Pointer? {
        handle ?: return null

        return Kernel32.INSTANCE.MapViewOfFile(handle, WinNT.SECTION_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    fun unmapViewOfFile(pointer: Pointer) {
        Kernel32Impl.KERNEL_32.UnmapViewOfFile(pointer)
        lastError = Kernel32Impl.INSTANCE.GetLastError()
    }
}
```

Then on the actual usage of that:

```kotlin
windowsService.openMemoryMapFile(MEMORY_MAP_FILE_NAME)?.let { handle ->
            windowsService.mapViewOfFile(handle)?.let { pointer ->
                val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BLOCK_SIZE)
                buffer.put(pointer.getByteArray(0, BLOCK_SIZE))
                buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                buffer.rewind()
```